# Add user to group automatically after registration in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I installed Groups plugin in Wordpress and I want to add user to group automatically after registration in Wordpress.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Settings>General>New User Default Role ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in your functions.php

```
   add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
    function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
            do_shortcode('[groups_join group="Knitting"]');
        }
```